# How do I create an array using the for-each loop structure?

Tags: java, arrays, loops, foreach

How would you create an array with user input using the for-each loop structure?

I would normally do:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Include a number into the array:");
    array[i] = sc.nextInt();
}
```

How can I do the same thing but using a for-each style loop?

Comment: Counter-question: why should we use a `foreach`-loop? We loose the index-information, which we clearly need to access the specific array-element.

Comment: hi @AdrianMantilla - for (T curr : collection) - is for when you have already gathered the contents of the collection ..

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop with the values of the indices. You could use an [`IntStream.range(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#range-int-int-) to generate the valid indices and combine that with a `forEach`. Like,

```
IntStream.range(0, array.length).forEach(i -> {
    System.out.println("Include a number into the array:");
    array[i] = sc.nextInt();
});
```